# How to handle (failed) login attempts with Smack XMPP API

Tags: java, authentication, xmpp, smack

I'm developing a chat server based on XMPP and Smack API, which connects to an Openfire server (Hosted by a friend who is also developing this with me).

So, I started programming it just a few days ago (Netbeans on OS X 10.8), and today I went on to the connection and login aspects.

I can login perfectly with the right choice of username+password :P but I don't know how to handle an invalid login attempt and let the app show a message and then allowing the user to retry.

Here's my code, which fires after user has pressed a button in my Swing JForm:

(Note: XMPPConnection object is already created in another class, and the connection has been made to the server. You can see I'm calling the object from that another class)

```
private void btnIniciarSesionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    String Usuario = txtUsuario.getText();
    String Password = new String (pwdContrasena.getPassword());

    if (Usuario.equals("") || Password.equals("")){
        // Missing data
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Missing data");
    }
    else{
        //Try to login
        try{
            Proyecto_chat.conexion.login(Usuario, Password, "x");
        }
        catch (XMPPException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Ventana_login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            // Problem
        }
        if (Proyecto_chat.conexion.isAuthenticated() == true){  //Login has been successful
            jLabel1.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Authenticated as " + Usuario);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Authenticated as " + Usuario);
            //Exit login window and carry on  
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "login error");
        }
    }
}
```

Should I play with that exception I'm getting? ->

```
SEVERE: null
SASL authentication DIGEST-MD5 failed: not-authorized: 
at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:337)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203)
at proyecto_chat.Ventana_login.btnIniciarSesionActionPerformed(Ventana_login.java:159)
at proyecto_chat.Ventana_login.access$100(Ventana_login.java:15)
at proyecto_chat.Ventana_login$2.actionPerformed(Ventana_login.java:73)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
(...) more lines that I think are not critical for this
```

As passwords are stored in plain text (University project, so it doesn't matter) for simplifying changing them from inside the application, I can connect to the database (PostgreSQL in remote server) from the client computer, and check the passwords and only do 'conexion.login' if user&pass matches, but that would be... you know... wrong

After looking around on the web with no luck, I decided to head over here, ask, go to sleep and wake up next morning with some suggestions ;)
Help shall be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the main problem was that when I tried to login using an invalid username/password, some exception was thrown (As well as an information display that I set up), but the application wouldn't let me log in again (As if I corrected my data and clicked the button again).

I finally solved this by placing the .connect() right behind the .login() method, and calling .disconnect() in case a bad login was made, so the server would be reconnected every time the user tried to log in .

This might not be the ideal approach, but I find it easy and do-able. Thanks for helping!

Comment: How do i handle errors, where username and password does not exist in database

Comment: @DeclanNnadozie This thread is from 2013 and I don't remember anything at all. You might be better off posting a new question and someone might be able to help out

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you are asking but if it's "How can I determine the reason for a failed login attempt with Smack?" then here is my answer:

You have to evaluate the (XMPP)Exception's message string as of Smack 3.2.2 if you want to determine the reason for the failed login. These message strings that distinguish between the various failure reasons are currently hard-coded in the source, which is usually not a good idea.

A while ago I have created [SMACK-416 "Improve Exceptions on connect() and login()"](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-426) to address this issue. The idea is to replace the hard-coded strings/failure reasons with a class hierarchy. But it sure will take a few months until this is implemented (and maybe a few weeks/months/years until it is released).

Comment: Actually, the main problem was that when I tried to login using an invalid username/password, some exception was thrown (As well as an information display that I set up), but the application wouldn't let me log in again (As if I corrected my data and clicked the button again). I finally solved this by placing the `.connect()` right behind the `.login()` method, and calling `.disconnect()` in case a bad login was made, so the server would be reconnected every time the user tried to log in

Comment: It would be great if those functions were in fact more "verbose" in terms of failure to connect and such ;)